# insert Blob type in database using hibernate and spring mvc

Tags: spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, blob

I have a jsp page with a form. In the form I have an input of type file, and the user is able to upload an image.

when validating the form, I have a controller that should inserts the image in the database as BLOB, but I couldn't do it.

I tried getting it using:

```
@RequestParam byte[] img
```

and then:

```
Blob imgB = new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(imgb);
```

but it didn't work.

I tried also:

```
@RequestParam File img
```

but I've got an error message saying I can't get it as File.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are using hibernate just create an entity which has a field of type `byte[]` and annotate it with `@Lob`. To receive files you need to enable spring multipart file upload .

Comment: ok, and how to enable spring multipart file upload ?

Comment: Just add a `MultipartResolver` as explained in [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart).

Comment: Now I'm getting the error: The current request is not a multipart request

Comment: Make sure you are setting the correct content type in the form. I strongly suggest reading up on how to do file uploads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean take a look

Comment: Thanks all, the problem is resolved !